# mod_rewrite: Make rules apply to both subdomains and subfolders

Tags: apache, subdomain, subdirectory, mod-rewrite

## Metadata

### My server setup

A shared host with wildcard subdomains and optional preceding www.
I can't touch httpd.conf and have limited .htaccess directives, although RewriteRule and the likes apply.

I use per-directory .htaccess files.

### My server layout

**Most** subfolders (read: some are for gfx and such) are standalone applications, f.ex: A URL shortener, a image upload site.

### Usual PHP controller setup

To manipulate applications, f.ex. view a specific file that's been uploaded, I read the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in order to use URIs like `http://s.domain.com/?image.jpg` to retrieve it from where it's stored.

*This setup may differ from application to application.*

## Problem

### What I have

#### Examples

**URL Shortener:**

`http://s.domain.com/?xy7r` OR `http://www.domain.com/s/?xy7r` retrieves the hash from a database and redirects the user.

**Image Uploader:**

`http://d.domain.com/?xy7r.png` OR `http://www.domain.com/d/?xy7r.png` redirects to `http://d.domain.com/u/xy7r.png`

*(Note: the www. is optional in all cases)*

### What I want

Adjust my existing applications to use Apache's mod_rewrite.

#### Examples

**URL Shortener:**

`http://s.domain.com/xy7r` OR `http://www.domain.com/s/xy7r`

**Image Uploader:**

`http://d.domain.com/xy7r.png` OR `http://www.domain.com/d/xy7r.png`

### My approach

At first I was adding RewriteRules like a happy hacker and everything worked fine,
I then noticed that as they were designed for URIs like `http://sub.domain.com` they did not work for
URIs like `http://www.domain.com/sub`.

I decided to try and set up conditions so that the rules would work for both URI cases.
So I Google-FUd and read specifications, documentations and tutorials. I do not fully understand this directive but neither do I think I found any appropriate solutions nor similar problems on the net.

I then gave up and thought I'd instead redirect the second URI syntax (`http://www.domain.com/sub/`) to the preferred one (`http://sub.domain.com`) *(Also `http://www.sub.domain.com`)*, to then apply my existing `RewriteRule`'s

### My .htaccess so far

*(Only for the **URL Shortener** as I have not moved on until I get it working)*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^s\.domain\.com$ [NC]  # Exclude correct URI
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$  # Exclude old HTTP requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/s($|/.*$)  # Rewrite bad URI
RewriteRule ^.* http://s.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent]  # Redirect to correct URI

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fonts/  # Exclude system folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php  # Exclude system file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/style.css  # -||-
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script.js  # -||-
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/short.php  # -||-
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://s.domain.com/?$1  # Rewrite to actual URI
```

### What I get

URI's like `http://s.domain.com/xy7r` work, as do the same preceded by www., but
the `http://www.domain.com/s/xy7r` URI syntax just redirects to `http://s.domain.com` and ignores the **xy7r** part.

## Question

Am I on the right track or is there a better/more correct way to do this?
I've been trying to understand the `RewriteBase` directive but I don't understand it at all, and trying values like `RewriteBase /s/` or `s` or `/s` don't satisfy.

In any way I am at a fullstop, I do not know how to proceed.
Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

`</WOT>`

Comment: On the 5th line, replace `^.*` with `^(.*)$` and on the last line get rid of the question mark (why is it there?)

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.
The questionmark is there to rewrite it to s.domain.com/?the_text as my PHP scripts reads the QUERY_STRING as mentioned in the beginning of my post.

Comment: Hmm OK .. the question mark shouldn't be the issue though. It's the first thing I mentioned.

Comment: It does not work. More information:

Line 5 was originally: `RewriteRule ^.* http://s.domain.com%1 [R=permanent]` (notice the %)

I tried with your approach, it kept working with the `s.domain.com/xy7r` approach but `domain.com/s/xy7r` still redirected the same.

It seems to me that it redirects to s.domain.com and then the rest of the rules won't match at all.

Line 5 now:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://s.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent]`

I also tried with: `%1` on the above line.

No luck.

Comment: Oh. While it doesn't work just yet, I just noticed my php script was redirecting to s.domain.com if the hash could not be found in the database. Changing that to print `$_SERVER` reveals that what it gets is:

`[REQUEST_URI] => /?http://s.domain.com/2p1bq`

Comment: I moved to an answer below ...

Answer (score 0):

For the first set of rules, replace

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/s($|/.*$)  # Rewrite bad URI
RewriteRule ^.* http://s.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent]  # Redirect to correct URI
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^s/?(.*) http://s.domain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Yes!, now we're talking. Seems to work.

Though: `http://www.domain.com/s` and `http://www.domain.com/s/` with or without the `www.` redirects to `http://s.domain.com/?index.php`

I've tried changing it to:
`RewriteRule ^s/(.*) http://s.domain.com/$1 [L,R=302]` _(removing the questionmark)_

but that makes no difference.

Also, a question: Why 302: Moved Temporarily, shouldn't be Permanently Moved?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does the index.php come from? Is there more to the .htaccess? And sorry, the 302 was a typo. Make it 301.

Comment: I don't know. I guess it somehow gets it from the DirectoryIndex. Perhaps in the core httpd.conf which I can not access. Trying different approaches, basically (as far as I can comprehend) is that it should not add the questionmark if there is nothing behind the trailing slash or no trailing slash at all in the URI `domain.com/s/` as redirecting to `s.domain.com/index.php` is fine.

Comment: Still the same.
Odd though because `www.domain.com/s/style.css` doesn't redirect but shows the file (which I guess is fine), `www.domain.com/s/script.js` also doesn't redirect and shows the file.
But `www.domain.com/s/index.php` redirects to `s.domain.com/?index.php`, seems there must be some other rule that causes this. My embedded .htaccess content is complete though.

Comment: I guess then add another line in your second set of rules: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$  # -||-